# Roll a fair die. You lose as many dollars as the number of pips (spots on the dies) that are showing...

Tags: probability

Then you toss a fair coin as many times as the number of pips. For each heads, you win \$20; for each tails, you lose \$1. Let X = total amount you win (or lose if $X<0$).

What is $E(X)$?

**My thoughts:**

If you roll $n$ you lose $n$ and then gain ($20 \cdot$ expected head) $-$ ($1 \cdot$ expected tails)

Expected heads = expected tails = $\frac{n}{2}$.

Probability of rolling $n$ is $\frac{1}{6}$. Therefore:

$E(X) = \sum_{n=1}^6 \frac{-n + 20\frac{n}{2} - 1\frac{n}{2}}{6}$

$= \sum_{n=1}^6 \frac{-n + 10n - \frac{n}{2}}{6}$

$= \sum_{n=1}^6 \frac{8.5n}{6}$

$= \frac{8.5}{6}\cdot \frac{6\cdot7}{2}= \frac{(8.5)\cdot7}{2} = 29.75$

Does this work seem correct? I feel like I did something wrong. Thanks!

Comment: [lgtm](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LGTM)

Comment: looks dandy to me (I got the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y\sim{\cal U}\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ be the result of rolling a die (a discrete uniform distribution).

Let $Z_i\sim{\cal U}\{-1, 20\}$ be the return from tossing one coin, for coins: $i\in\{1\ldots 6\}$.  The coin tosses are mutually independent.

Then by linearity of expectation we obtain your result.

$$\begin{align}
{\large\mathbb E}[X] & = {\large\mathbb E}\left[-Y+\sum_{k=1}^Y Z_k\right]
\\[0.5ex]
 & = {\large\mathbb E}[Y]\times(-1+{\large\mathbb E}[Z_\ast])
\\[0.5ex]
 & = \left(\sum_{y=1}^6 \frac y 6\right)\left(-1+\frac{-1}{2}+\frac {20}{2}\right)
\\[0.5ex]
 & = \frac{21}{6} \times \frac {17} 2
\\[0.5ex]
 & = 29.75
\end{align}$$